# Working with multiple threads and Connectionpool in UnboundID LDAP

Tags: multithreading, java-8, connection-pooling, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Considering the huge load that I am getting for authentication, using multiple threads and `Connectionpool` will be a best solution to handle the load. However I have two design options in my mind

> 1. Pass Connectionpool to individual threads as argument and get a connection to do the bind request from ConnectionPool
> 2. Pass connection to threads rather than passing Connectionpool to threads and do bind request

Which Design would you prefer most and what are the reasons for them?

Comment: pass the existing connection to the thread

Comment: then how can I release the connection. What is the reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for this question after a discussion happened with UnboundIDSDK forum. I will add the final finding for others. according to [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/ldap-sdk/discussion/1001257/thread/f7f00ed1/?limit=25)
It is recommended to available the pool to threads by passing the pool to thread as argument.

```
public BindResult doBind(LDAPConnectionPool pool, 
                     BindRequest bindRequest)
         throws LDAPException
{
 return pool.bind(bindRequest);
}
```